# What is the different between laravel PLUCK and SELECT

Tags: php, laravel, select, pluck

I've found that Laravel's `pluck()` method returns a plain array and `select()` returns an object.

Can anyone explain if there are any other differences between these two methods?

Comment: There's a little known Laravel API that details all the methods available. For your question, check these 3: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_select, https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck and https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_pluck. The 2 `pluck()` methods are mostly the same, but one is on the Database Builder class, while the other is on a Collection (result of `->get()`, etc)

Answer (score 5):

### Select

EX : `DB::table('users')->select('id', 'name', 'email)`

**Select** is a method sent to the database that Laravel will translate as
`SELECT id, name, email FROM users`

This will select the data of the columns you asked and nothing else. It allows you to be more efficient with your request by only asking the required data. Take the example above and image that the user is a Facebook user. It has a ton of data on it, plus relations to other tables. If you just want to display the name, email and a link to the user profile, doing this request!

For more info and knowing more about the expected response visit : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements

### Pluck

EX:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('roles', '=', 'admin')
$emails = $users->pluck('email')
```

The **Pluck** method retrieves the values in a collection that you already got from the Database and that is now a Laravel [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections). This allows you to create an array of the plucked data, but will not improve the performance of your request, as in the Example above, the **$users** would hold all data of all the admin users.

**Since it does not improve performance, what good is it then ?**
The pluck would be useful for example to separate some datas in different variables depending on where. You might need the users data for some stuffs, but also want to display a quick list of all emails together.

For more info about the pluck method and understand how to create a keyed array from a second column, visit the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 4):

Pluck is a Laravel Collections method used to extract certain values from the collection. You might often want to extract certain data from the collection i.e Eloquent collection.

While Select is a normal selection of either multi or specific columns. They are

By using `Pluck` you only ask to return necessary fields, but with `get` you will pull all columns. Also select does the same & the difference here is between the returning result. Using pluck cause returning the final result as an array with pair of given arguments, but select return an array (or object) which every single child contain one row.

`$name = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->pluck('name');`

Answer (score 3):

The answers are kinda weird so I'll give my 2 cents.

```
Countries::pluck('name');
```

returns this to my frontend:

```
["Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Afghanistan"]
```

while:

```
Countries::select('name')->get();
```

returns:

```
[{name: 'Andorra'}, {name: 'United Arab Emirates'}, {name: 'Afghanistan'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually select is used inside DB queries, which can affect the performance by limiting the pulled columns. However, Pluck is Laravel Collection's method, so  you can use pluck after you pull the data from DB.

Answer (score 2):

Pluck function normally used to pull a single column from the collection or with 2 columns as key, value pairs, which is always be a single dimension array.

Select will return all of the columns you specified for an entity in a 2 dimensional array, like array of selected values in an array.

**Note:** Pluck function is a collection function which happens after the data is fetched. Select is a query builder function that builds query to perform in the database server.